# Equivalent of \today in org mode

Tags: emacs, datetime, org-mode

Is there any equivalent of \today in org mode which auto updates whenever the document is exported and can be inserted anywhere in text?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the `time` [macro](http://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-replacement.html).

For example,

```
* Date test
This is the export time: {{{time(%Y-%m-%d)}}}.
```

Will produce the export date.

For the format of the time specification, check the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Parsing.html) for `format-time-string`.

Comment: Hi .. it is {{{date}}} macro. Time doesn’t work

Comment: @Vaibhav I'm using orgmode 9.1, and I tested the example before posting. {{{date}}} is for the #+DATE property, {{{time}}} is for the export time.